# Java Accessing Hexadecimal Text Files For HashMaping

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, hex, bufferedreader

I am making a GUI were I have to make buttons and the background changes. The program is using a Java Collection Framework were I went with a Hashmap. I am really having trouble understanding and trying to do is access a txt file then read the pairs and store them in the hashmap. the txt file contains the pairs color - hexadecimal value on separate lines which will sort the pairs in the increasing order of their hexadecimal values and use iterators to display the sorted pairs to the console. I tried a BufferReader but got errors but I am guessing that is no the best way to use for a map.

//Input File.txt

Red FF0000

Blue 000084

Green 00FF00

Yellow FFFF00

Orange FF8C00

Pink FFC0CB

Grey D3D3D3

Brown 964B00

Purple 800080

Black 000000

Dark green 013220

Dark Red 8B0000

Dark blue 00008B

Dark Orange D97700

Dark grey 363737

Dark Purple 471E8A

Dark yellow 7f7f00

Light Yellow FFFFCC

Light Blue C0D9D9

Light Purple D8BFD8

Here is the code to get that I already started and finally got working for the GUI.

```
public class FP extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Input File.txt")));
private Map<String, String> buttonColors;

// Constructor
public FP() {

    super("ColorMap");
    buttonColors = new HashMap<String, String>();

    //test button
    buttonColors.put("Red", "FF0000");

    setSize(400, 400);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> coloringButtons : buttonColors
            .entrySet()) {

        JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(coloringButtons.getKey());

        button.setActionCommand(coloringButtons.getValue());
        button.addActionListener(this);

        // Add this new color-button to the button group
        buttonGroup.add(button);
        add(button);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String color = e.getActionCommand();
    getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(Integer.parseInt(color, 16)));

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FP obj = new FP();
    obj.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Please show us what code failed. Currently this reads like a request for code instead of a question.

Comment: Sorry I just changed the `BufferedReader` section to a `static String fileName = "Input File.txt";` because I thought this would help the Hashmap @ Maarten Bodewes

Comment: I hope that is a good start for the hashmap in order to access the file

Comment: You need to show us what you tried with the `BufferedReader` and how it failed.

Comment: okay, at the top I replaced the buffered reader were it was giving issues were I first started. `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Input File.txt")));`

Comment: Ah, "giving issues" is a new entry in my collection of vague error descriptions, thanks for that. You should usually not use a `BufferedReader` as a field, you need to use it inside a method.

Comment: as an inside method? sorry this is my first time trying to access a txt file and store it to a hashmap

Comment: [Try the I/O tuturials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#textfiles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is your code modified to read the file and populate a HashMap, in this case I am using a TreeMap to sort the hex fields in order, see if this works for you,

public class FP extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
private TreeMap<String, String> buttonColors;

// Constructor
public FP() {

    super("ColorMap");
    buttonColors = new TreeMap<String, String>();

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("InputFile.txt");
    while(true)
    {
      String str = br.readLine();
      if(str==null)break;
      if(str.length()==0)continue;
      string[] st = str.split(" ");
      string colorName = st[0].trim();
      string colorValue = st[1].trim();

      //* to have the colors sorted by the hex value
      buttonColors.put(colorValue, colorName);
    }
    br.close();

    //test button
    //buttonColors.put("Red", "FF0000");

    setSize(400, 400);
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> coloringButtons : buttonColors
            .entrySet()) {

        JRadioButton button = new JRadioButton(coloringButtons.getValue());

        button.setActionCommand(coloringButtons.getKey());
        button.addActionListener(this);

        // Add this new color-button to the button group
        buttonGroup.add(button);
        add(button);
    }
}
```

Comment: this `BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileInputStream("InputFile.txt");` is still giving me an issue saying "The constructor BufferedReader(FileInputStream) is undefined"?

Comment: now this is weird. It says it can't find the file now. I am using eclipse too by the way. with what you gave me but I had to modify it

Comment: try to use the full path to the file and see if this solves the issue

Comment: how would you type that in? Folder/Input File.txt?

Comment: let; assume your file name is inputfile.txt and it is located in the test/source/buttons then on linux/unix it will be "/test/source/buttons/inputfile.txt" and if it is on windows, then let' assume the folder is on the c: drive, then it will be "c:\\test\\souce\\buttons\\inputfile.txt"